# Alternativa a "excluir" para apagar um post

Tags: debate, bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Seria possivel usar a palavra *apagar* ou *remover* em vez de *excluir* para apagar um post?

Para português de Portugal é mais claro o objectivo/função.

Comment: Não vejo porque não. Fica claro para todo mundo. Prefere apagar ou remover?

Comment: @bigown: _remover_ talvez seja a melhor variante.

Comment: Eu creio que 'remover' dá uma noção melhor do que 'apagar'. Apagar muitas vezes é associado a limpar um campo, e não a remover completamente o conjunto. Só de curiosidade, 'excluir' em pt_PT dá noção do que?

Comment: @Bacco, em PT_pt excluír não se usa neste contexto, eu usaria excluir se uma pessoa fôr isolada e ignorada por outros num grupo: for *excluída*.

Comment: @sergio grato pela explicação, é sempre bom entender as diferenças!

Comment: Estou um pouco atrasado, mas ninguém falou em "deletar". No Brasil já é bastante comum, e inclusive faz parte da [lista oficial de palavras da língua](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23). Não sei o que pensam os portugueses.

Comment: @bfavaretto, "deletar" funciona porque estamos infetados com o inglês e dá para perceber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alterei tudo que encontrei de "excluir" para "remover" (e variações) e algumas coisas para "apagar", onde achei que faziam mais sentido.

Já foi pro ar e, como sempre, se alguma coisa ficar esquisita, só avisar!

Comment: Sobraram umas coisas esquisitas na [aba "apagar" das ferramentas de moderação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today): está "apagar votos" em vez de "votos para remover"; "desfazer exclusão de votos" em vez de "votos para desfazer remoção"; "excluído recentemente" em vez de "removido recentemente"; "exclusão desfeita recentemente" em vez de "remoção desfeita recentemente"

Comment: @bfavaretto beleza, vou acertar

Comment: @bfavaretto Pronto. A interface de traduçào não mostra o contexto, só os termos. Então às vezes tem que se traduzir "Delete votes" às cegas e dá nisso :)

Comment: Será que você trocou um outro "delete votes"? Ainda vejo "apagar votos" naquela página.

Comment: As alterações só vão pro ar quando tem um build novo. Não sei se rolou algum depois que eu alterei. Se ainda tiver lá amanhã, eu revejo

Answer (score 8):

Baseado no conversado nos comentários, eu votaria pela palavra "Remover" neste caso.