# Erro na tradução de "closure"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na página que mostra os detalhes dos seus próprio votos (`http://br.stackoverflow.com/users/ID/username?tab=votes` - não vou colocar como link porque ninguém além do próprio usuário pode ver seus votos) a palavra "closure" está traduzida como "conclusão":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugiro usar "fechar", mesmo porque o item ao lado está como "reabrir". Os demais itens estão OK (talvez exceto pelo "exclusão", pois como sugerido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/72/alternativa-a-excluir-para-apagar-um-post) "remoção" seria uma alternativa mais amigável aos usuários de Portugal - e igualmente compreensível pelos do Brasil).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atualmente, os tipos de voto são:

`todos | a favor | contra | remover | restaurar | fechar | reabrir`