# Utilizar "Utilizadores" em vez de "Usuários"

Tags: debate, tradução

Não seria preferível em vez de se usar "Usuários" ter a palavra "Utilizadores" como norma no site? "Utilizadores" é mais neutro em termos de segregação "PT - PT" e "PT - BR".

Esta pergunta vem no sentido que "Utilizadores" é uma palavra de português utilizada em todas as variantes da língua, enquanto que "usuários" é uma palavra meramente utilizada no Brasil.

Comment: "Utilizadores" não é utilizado (hahaha) no Brasil. Talvez a única forma realmente neutra seja *users*, em inglês.

Comment: A sério? 0% de utilização como a palavra "Usuários" fora do Brasil? Se é esse o caso, então concordo com utilizar "users" como um meio termo. Acho que se deveria tentar manter o Português do StackOverflow PT o mais neutro possível, sem inclinar a balança para nenhum dialecto em particular.

Comment: Não vejo problema em misturar, há várias coisas bem de Portugal no site também, e a única vez que eu vi dar dúvida no sentido, foi "defeito", que pra PT é "default", e pra nós dá o sentido de algo que não está funcionando corretamente. Qualquer padronização é uma forma de inclinar permanentemente a balança. Sugiro "deixar a balança balançando", enquanto não causar problema.

Comment: Discussão relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/deveremos-de-manter-algum-standard-linguistico-ou-n%C3%A3o

Comment: @Bacco aqui "defeito" também tem esse sentido, de algo que não está a funcionar corretamente. Mas se disseres "por defeito" já quer dizer *default*.
Padrão também se usa aqui, embora muito menos.

Comment: Assim como en-US tem prioridade sobre en-UK, aqui no site a preferência é por pt-BR. Tamanho importa.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é usar "Pessoa" no lugar. Não gosto muito do termo, mas fica ok tanto em pt-PT quanto em pt-BR. Exemplo: ["Digite para localizar pessoas"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users). Mas certas coisas ficam estranhas. O `<title>` do [perfil](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/429/guilherme-bernal)... utilizar "Conta de Fulano", talvez? E "conta principal"/"conta meta" para trocar entre perfil principal e do meta? Meio estranho, mas parece funcionar.

Answer (score 5):

Creio não haver solução fácil nesse caso. De fato, "utilizadores" não é empregado no Brasil, entretanto está em português e é compreensível (se eu visse esse termo num site pt_PT não teria dúvidas quanto ao quê ele significa). "users", por outro lado, tampouco é comumente empregado, mas passa a impressão de um site mal-traduzido (e pode-se argumentar que é menos compreensível também).

Sobre manter a linguagem o mais neutra possível, eu sou suspeito pra falar (pois sou brasileiro, e essa situação é bastante "cômoda" pra mim), mas [segundo o Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/54/215) não é esse o objetivo da Stack Exchange para o SOpt: o site foi pensado tendo os brasileiros como principal público-alvo, ainda que de forma não-excludente para os demais lusófonos. Dessa forma, ainda que seja consenso na comunidade não restringir o dialeto no que tange à participação (temos nos esforçado para, por exemplo, não permitir edições que convertam termos de pt_PT para pt_BR), a localização da interface de usuário foi feita explicitamente para pt_BR.

Dito isso, eu não seria contra se as coisas mudassem, só não é algo com o qual eu pretenda gastar minhas energias. Se é compreensível, eu deixaria quieto, e se não é, sou a favor de se buscar alternativas (exemplo: [excluir vs. remover](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/72/215)). De modo que eu pergunto: "usuários" é compreensível? Se a resposta for "não", de minha parte poderíamos mudar para "utilizadores" sem problemas...

Comment: Eu falo por mim, só percebi o que queria dizer "usuários", das primeiras vezes que vi a palavra, só pelo sitio onde se encontrava, por exemplo "login de usuário". http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/usuario

Answer (score 4):

Até entendo que o português do Brasil tem preferência por ser maioria.

Mas, pelo que foi comentado, tenho a impressão de que "Utilizadores" é bem mais compreensível para os brasileiros do que "Usuários" para os portugueses. Portanto, entre esses dois, ficaria com "Utilizadores".

---

Porém acho que a melhor alternativa seria ***Membro***.

Pelo menos para mim, "membro", neste contexto, é praticamente um sinônimo de "usuário" (bem mais claro que "utilizador", por sinal). Gostaria de ouvir dos portugueses o que eles acham.